# Bash autocomplete

Tags: linux, bash, cmd, script, shell

Estoy creando un menú interactivo en Bash donde deseo que  al estar escribiendo una entrada de text, al mismo tiempo vaya leyendo un archivo.txt y con esa información nos muestre opciones para autocompletar nuestra entrada, algo asi como el autocomplete en jquery. La pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma de realizar esto?
el codigo es:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then

        echo "========"
        read -e -p "HOSTNAME: " HOST
        ./menu.bash $HOST
elif [ -n "$2" ]; then

        clear
        echo "ssh $(whoami)@$1"
else

        HOST=$1
        cat ../data/hosts | egrep ".+\s+\\$HOST"
        echo "========"
        read -e -p "HOSTNAME: " -i "$HOST" HOST2
        ./menu.bash $HOST2
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mire este sitio [bash-programmable-completion-tutorial](https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial.html)

te puede ser de ayuda, puedes probar esto. crea un archivo **autocompletar.sh** con lo sigiente

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

main(){

COMANDO="$@"
DIR='/bin/'$COMANDO

if [ -f $DIR  ]; then
    echo "YA ESTA CREADO"
    $COMANDO
else

    echo "
#/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z \"$1\" ]; then
  echo \"Ingrese el comando $COMANDO <tab><tab>\"
  exit 2
fi

exists=$(fc -l -1000 | grep ^$1 -- 2>/dev/null)

if [ -n \"$exists\" ]; then
  fc -s -- \"$1\"
else
  echo \"Command with number $1 was not found in recent history\"
  exit 2
fi
    ">$DIR

    chmod +x $DIR

    echo "este es el contenido de prueba del archivo plano">$DIR-test.txt

    echo "
#/usr/bin/env bash
complete -W \"$(cat "$DIR-test.txt")\" $COMANDO
        ">$DIR'-completion.bash'

        chmod +x+w $DIR'-completion.bash'
        source $DIR'-completion.bash'

        echo "HECHO" && $COMANDO

    fi
}

main "$@"
```

Luego ejecutalo en la terminal

```
~$ sudo chmod +x autocompletar.sh && ./autocompletar.sh autocompletar
~$ source /bin/autocompletar'-completion.bash'
~$ autocompletar <tab><tab>
```

listo mostrara el contenido del archivo.txt